# Are there tools that would be suitable for maintaining a changelog for a Cabal Haskell package?

Tags: haskell, packaging, software-distribution, cabal

I'm working fast and furiously on a new Haskell package for compiler writers.  I'm going through many minor version numbers daily, and the Haskell packaging system, [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/), doesn't seem to offer any tools for updating version numbers or for maintaining a change log.  (Logs are going into `git` but that's not visible to anyone using the package.)  I would kill for something equivalent to Debian's `uupdate` or `dch`/`debchange` tools.

Does anyone know of **general-purpose tools that could be used to increment version numbers automatically and add an entry to a change log?**

Comment: This now has 14 votes and zero answers. I'm not sure exactly what you want.  Extracting the change log into a file to include with the distribution sounds like a 1-line script.  A few more lines of script should be able to get the file versions from a nominated tag and build a package with a version number based on the tag.  So if its not that, what exactly do you need?

Comment: @Paul: There is no change log to extract.  The git log is certainly not appropriate for distribution, although it would be useful information for a developer creating a change log.  As for what I am looking for, I want a tool like `uupdate` that will manage things like version numbers and changelog edits.  I agree it's probably a script but probably 100 lines not 10 lines.  I'll probably tackle one this summer.

Answer (score 2):

I use a very simple scheme to generate my `CHANGELOG`. I just ask `darcs` for it and include it in the `extra-files` section of my package's `.cabal` file. Though, this seems too simplistic for what you are asking. =)

That said, you can go quite a bit farther and use a custom cabal `Setup.(hs|lhs)` that builds the `CHANGELOG` during `cabal sdist` out of your `darcs` or `git` repository's commit info (or out of whatever system you decide to use to track it)

The [`Setup.lhs`](http://allmydata.org/trac/darcs-2/browser/Setup.lhs) used by `darcs` does something very similar to include information on version numbers and number of applied patches since the last version. Look at the `sdistHook` and `generateVersionModule` machinery in [`Setup.lhs`](http://allmydata.org/trac/darcs-2/browser/Setup.lhs) to get an idea of how this can be done.

Comment: I'm a frequent, compulsive committer, and I don't want my users to suffer through my RCS logs...

Answer (score 0):

To non-answer your question, I'm not aware of anything. This sounds like a good match for posting in the [Haskell Proposals](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell_proposals/) subreddit, since it seems like a pretty useful idea.